# Changing connection string at runtime – is this correct approach?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ef-code-first, sql-server-ce, entity-framework-6

I have an application that connects to SQL Server and SQL CE databases with same schema. I am trying to explore if I can use same data-access layer to work with both type of databases. Everything seem to work fine with SQL Server. When connecting to SQL CE, I am trying to change connection string at runtime as followed

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Model1 db = new Model1();

            String CEConnectionString = @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\EmployeesCE.sdf;;Password=mypassword;Persist Security Info=True";
            db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = CEConnectionString;
            db.Persons.Add(new Person() { ID = 33, Name = "Sam", Description = "new stuff" });
            db.SaveChanges();

        }
```

For now I am getting following error when trying to Add a new person in the database.

> Unable to complete operation. The supplied SqlConnection does not
>   specify an initial catalog or AttachDBFileName.

Is this right approach to change the connection string at runtime to work with SQL CE database? If so what connection string should be used for SQL CE to get rid of this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the DefaultConnectionFactory, using code based config:

```
public class MyConfiguration : DbConfiguration 
{ 
    public MyConfiguration() 
    { 
        SetDefaultConnectionFactory(new SqlCeConnectionFactory("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0","...","...")); 
    } 
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj680699.aspx

Comment: I am not getting any DefaultConnectionFactory for Database. Do I need to include any assembly in references?

Comment: Actually getting this error: Member 'System.Data.Entity.Database.DefaultConnectionFactory.get' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Comment: if I do Database.DefaultConnectionFactory (without context) then code runs without any compilation error but it still write in SQL Server database (and not in CE). Any suggestions?